# Creating a bar plot with new data

Tags: r, matrix, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar plot of the average number of units per customer by Lifestage and I'm unable to figure out how to plot this data. It's basically a 7x2 matrix with the first column being life stage and the second column being the respective "unit per customer". Does anyone know what code I can use to create a bar plot with this new vector?

```
units_by_lifestage <- aggregate(data$PROD_QTY, 
                            by=list(data$LIFESTAGE), 
                            FUN=sum)
```

#Calculate the average number of units per customer by LIFESTAGE

```
units_per_customer_by_lifestage <- units_by_lifestage$x / customers_by_lifestage$x


mat <- as.matrix(units_per_customer_by_lifestage)

LIFESTAGE <- c("MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES", "NEW FAMILIES", "OLDER FAMILIES","OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES","RETIREES","YOUNG FAMILIES","YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES")

new_mat <- cbind(LIFESTAGE, mat)

new_mat
```

below is output of str(new_mat) to give an idea of the data

```
 chr [1:7, 1:2] "MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES" "NEW FAMILIES" "OLDER FAMILIES" "OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES" "RETIREES" "YOUNG FAMILIES" "YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "LIFESTAGE" "" output
```

with the respective data for `units_per_customer_by_lifestage` being:

```
1.901697, 1.857781, 1.946410, 1.913354, 1.892593, 1.940460, 1.834025
```

Comment: You should share some of your data.

Comment: @JohnPolo Hi John, please let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Use `dput(data)` to share your data in the future. If the output is a lot, use `dput(head(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

"New data", as you call it, doesn't change how one creates a bar plot. Your post is about a pretty basic question and quite likely a duplicate.

There is the base `barplot()`:

```
df <- data.frame(lifestage = c("MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES", "NEW FAMILIES", "OLDER FAMILIES", "OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES", "RETIREES", "YOUNG FAMILIES", "YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES"), units = c(1.901697, 1.857781, 1.946410, 1.913354, 1.892593, 1.940460, 1.834025))

barplot(units~lifestage, df)
```

You can also use the `ggplot2` library.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y=units, x=lifestage)) + geom_col()
```

The `geom_col()` function is one of two ways to create the barplot. I don't remember the other function off the top of my head. The `ggplot2` figure looks like this:

[image: barplot of data]

The axis labels are a little simplified because I was quick with recreating your data frame. The axis labels by default reflect the actual names for the columns called. To customize the axis labels you would add `lab()` like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=units, x=lifestage)) + geom_col() + labs(x="test")
```